# APNsPHP for iOS Push Notification

Tags: ios, push-notification, apns-php

I am a beginner to iOS development but managed to create certificate for the APNs Push Notification and implemented in my server using APNsPHP. After lots of search I managed to connected to the `gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com` but I am getting an error as :

> Sat, 04 Aug 2018 13:13:50 +0200 ApnsPHP[16266]: INFO: Trying gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195... Sat, 04 Aug 2018 13:13:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[16266]: INFO: Connected to gateway.sandbox.push.apple.com:2195. Sat, 04 Aug 2018 13:13:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[16266]: INFO: Sending messages queue, run #1: 1 message(s) left in queue. Sat, 04 Aug 2018 13:13:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[16266]: STATUS: Sending message ID 1 [custom identifier: Message-Badge-3] (1/3): 167 bytes. Sat, 04 Aug 2018 13:13:51 +0200 ApnsPHP[16266]: INFO: Disconnected.

What exactly am I doing wrong here? Because I am not getting any notification. Or how I will proceed further.

Comment: are you able to provide your code snippet how to send a push? What payload you are trying to send? Please include it in your question

Comment: U solved this problem?